# ViewController don't access your elements

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, swift2

I have a class that ViewController.swift linked to a UIViewController in my storyboard:

[image]

I have another class called ExpandableViewController and in it I try to resend ViewController:

```
    var viewController:UIViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ExpandableViewController") as UIViewController
    self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

But my viewController variable can not access the variable button in this class ViewController.swift am unable to create this subclass in ExpandableViewController.

How could I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Couple of issues:

```
var viewController:UIViewController
```

should be

```
var viewController:ViewController
```

You have subclassed UIViewController as ViewController

It would also be a good idea to give ViewController a storyboard id that is not the same as your other custom class (ExpandableViewController).

You will want to do something like:

```
 let viewController:ViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController1") as! ViewController
    self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
    viewController.button.setTitle("TEST", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

Comment: So it is not available in the class, that's my problem.

let viewController:ViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ExpandableViewController") as! ViewController

ViewController appear red saying that dont have class ViewController

Comment: Does ViewController still exist?  If the error is - Use of undeclared type 'ViewController' - then you don't have a subclass of UIViewController called "ViewController".